# How can I find choir sheet music?

Tags: voice, sheet-music, choir

I am looking for sheet music for a particular song I'd like to sing with my choir.
I tried googling and searching in some online shops but wasn't lucky.

Is there some sort of specialized search engine, or catalog to search for choral sheet music?

*--

Sidenote: 
I am looking for a general answer to the question 'How to search for choir sheet music?' But if anyone happens to know the choir arrangement I'm looking for, I'd be happy of course :-) 
The song is "Wonderful dream" (aka. Holidays are coming, the song Coca-Cola is using in their Christmas Commercial).*

Comment: Well, there's always the option (if you can get ahold of any arrangement) to hire some music major to arrange it for you.  Undergrads are cheap :-)

Comment: The US customer service didn't know what commercial I was talking about. The german customer service did, but they don't have the sheet music available. It was worth a try, nevertheless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most extensive site is http://www.cpdl.org . There are also many chorale arrangements on IMSLP (http://www.imslp.org/) but that site also has orchestral, solo, opera, pieces, etc. CPDL is specifically focused on choral music.  What you will not find on either site is most music published in the past 50 years (or since 1923 for American users) since that music is in copyright. For that music you will probably have to purchase it online.

Comment: CPDL and IMSLP only have music that is in the public domain; broadly speaking, music composed before the year 1920. The song that this questioner is asking about was composed about fifteen years ago, and is under copyright, so it certainly would not appear on CPDL or IMSLP.

Comment: I know (hence the last two sentences) and thank you for the clarification -- I was trying to answer the main question about centralized databases for finding music and not so much the side note. To be totally pedantic, IMSLP has CC-licensed music in addition to music in the public domain, but most of that musc is by up and coming composers and not major figures.

Answer (score 8):

The song "Wonderful Dream" was written by [Melanie Thornton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanie_Thornton) (1967-2001). She was an American singer who had commercial success in Europe while remaining unknown in the USA; most published information about her seems to be from Germany.

I found a [vocal solo and piano arrangement published by Hal Leonard](http://www.jwpepper.com/Wonderful-Dream/10355184E.item#.UjN3hRaq_d4). It appears to be out of print from Hal Leonard, but if you click on the link it will take you to the J.W. Pepper music distribution company in the US, which has copies for sale.

It does not appear that there is a published choral arrangement.

I live in the USA, and in this country, if there is a choral arrangement in print, it is highly likely that it will be for sale at jwpepper.com.

Answer (score -1):

The sheet music with simple guitar chords and the vocal melody are in this link. https://www.musicnotes.com/sheetmusic/mtd.asp?ppn=MN0119679